# JavaScript getting first day of the week issue

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with JavaScript to get the first day of the week.
 Its working for most of the cases but when get to the first day of the month its giving wrong result.

Am I missing anything here??

Please consider below two cases:

1) Case of 05/02/2014:

```
<script>
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = d.getUTCDay();
    var indate = d.getUTCDate();
    var diff = indate - day + (day == 0 ? -7:0); // adjust when day is sunday
    var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
    document.write('\nday:' + day);
    document.write('\nindate:' + indate);
    document.write('\nsunday:' + sunday);
    document.write('\diff:' + diff);

</script>
```

> **Result**:  day:5  indate:2  sunday:Sun Apr 27 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700
>   (Pacific Daylight Time) diff:-3

2) Case of 05/01/2014:

```
<script>
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = d.getUTCDay();
    var indate = d.getUTCDate();
    var diff = indate - day + (day == 0 ? -7:0); // adjust when day is sunday
    var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
    document.write('\nday:' + day);
    document.write('\nindate:' + indate);
    document.write('\nsunday:' + sunday);
    document.write('\diff:' + diff);

</script>
```

> **Result**: day:4 indate:1 sunday:Fri Mar 28 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific
>   Daylight Time)diff:-3

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's two things causing this:

1. By using UTC, your date values being used are the previous day, in the evening. So on the first of May, it's using the last day of April.
2. The `setDate` method has a special case - when the argument is negative, it means a number of days before the last day of the previous month. Because of point #1, this means that on the first of May (which is treated as the last of April) it rewinds all the way to March 31 before rewinding 3 days, giving you March 28.

You need to first account for the time zone / UTC problem, and then account for the month boundary issue.

1. To fix the first, use `setDateUTC` instead of just `setDate`.
2. The second issue is trickier. The only solution I can find is to subtract milliseconds instead of days.

   ```
   new Date(d + diff * 24 * 3600 * 1000) // convert days to hours, then seconds, then milliseconds
   ```

Comment: We needed to use `new Date(fullYear, month, day - diff)` to avoid a bug in Safari. `(day+diff)` works correctly even if negative (see spec).

Answer (score 0):

you can look

```
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = d.getUTCDay();
    var indate = d.getUTCDate();
    var diff = indate - day + (day == 0 ? -6:0); // adjust when day is sunday
    var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
    document.write('\nday:' + day);
    document.write('\nindate:' + indate);
    document.write('\nsunday:' + sunday);
    document.write('\diff:' + diff);

    document.write('<br/>');

    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0));
    var day = d.getUTCDay();
    var indate = d.getUTCDate();
    var diff = indate - day + (day == 0 ? -6:0); // adjust when day is sunday
    var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
    document.write('\nday:' + day);
    document.write('\nindate:' + indate);
    document.write('\nsunday:' + sunday);
    document.write('\diff:' + diff);
```

output

```
day:5 indate:2 sunday:Sun Apr 27 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)diff:-3
day:4 indate:1 sunday:Sun Apr 27 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)diff:-3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0));
var day = d.getUTCDay();
var indate = d.getUTCDate();
var diff = indate - day;
if (diff < 0)
    diff = d.getDate() + diff;
var sunday = new Date(d.setDate(diff));
document.write('\nday:' + day);
document.write('\nindate:' + indate);
document.write('\nsunday:' + sunday);
document.write('\diff:' + diff);
document.write('\dateNumber:' + dateNumber);`